# Disable authentication when uploading to local pypi server

Tags: python, pip, pypi, pypiserver

I'm using `pypiserver` to start up a local server to host and serve python packages for development inside a sandbox. Is it possible to disable password authentication? The documentation [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver/#uploading-packages-from-sources-remotely) says

> Currently only password-protected uploads are supported!

But further down it also says:

> It is also possible to disable authentication even for uploads. To avoid lazy security decisions, read help for -P and -a options

I would like to not have to use a password if the tool supports such a feature since this is only for iterative development. Does anyone know if that's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `devpi-server`. Related command `devpi` allows entering user credentials via
`login` subcomamand. The login is then valid for 10 hours and can be stopped by `devpi logout`.

There are other nice features of `devpi-server` worth using - e.g. if your uploaded package contains
`tox.ini`, you can call `devpi test <packagename>`, it will download it, install in temporary
virtualenv, run tox in it and push to the devpi server results of the test.

Comment: Thanks, but is there no way to completely disable the login? If I'm going to be making a password, then I can put it in my `pypirc` and have it work for `pypiserver` as well.

Comment: `devpi-server` allows to use user account with empty password. You have to do the `login` anyway as the server shall know, who is talking to it. Note, that the server will require valid login only for limited set of commands (push, upload etc.), not for ordinary use like installing packages from it.

Answer (score 2):

from the documentation: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver#detailed-usage

```
-P, --passwords PASSWORD_FILE
   use apache htpasswd file PASSWORD_FILE to set usernames & passwords when
   authenticating certain actions (see -a option).
   If you want to allow un-authorized access, set this option and -a
   explicitly to empty (either '.' or'').
```

Based on this you would need to start your server like this:

```
./pypi-server -p 8080 -P -a
```

Actually I face the same problem but I'm running it under mod_wsgi. How do you disable authentication there?

Comment: For mod_wsgi, you can specify `password_file = ""` and `authenticated = ""` in your .wsgi script.